# Où est ma question sur des livres avancés de grammaire ?

Tags: support, questions, deleted-questions, deletion

Je cherche cette question, que je suis certain d'avoir posée il y a au moins 2 mois, sur la site principale. Néanmoins, je soupçonne qu'elle a été supprimée. Si oui, il m'est impossible de la dépister. SVP, pourrait-on m'épauler ?

Comment: Est-ce de [celle-ci](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8143/ressources-pour-%c3%a9tudiants-avanc%c3%a9s) dont tu parles? Elle est close et a par la suite été supprimée, elle n'est donc accessible que par son auteur dans son profil (et aux modérateurs et certains utilisateurs qui ont la possibilité de la restaurer).

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Oui, merci.

Answer (score 3):

En principe, l'état clos pour une question est temporaire : une question close a vocation à être soit rouverte, soit supprimée. Ce site est un site de questions-réponses, et une question à laquelle on ne peut plus répondre ne sert à rien. En général, ce qui permet à une question d'être rouverte, c'est d'être éditée pour la rendre convenable sans invalider les réponses existantes.

En pratique, nous avons tendance à laisser traîner les questions closes, essentiellement parce qu'il n'y a pas de bons outils pour les supprimer. Seuls les utilisateurs avec 2000 points de réputation (10000 lorsque la phase bêta sera terminée) peuvent voter l'effacement, sans bonne interface pour le faire (il n'y a pas de queue de revue d'effacement comme il y a des queues de revue pour la fermeture et la réouverture).

En tant que modérateur, de temps en temps, je parcours les questions closes et j'efface celles qui. Voici les critères que j'applique :

- La question est close depuis suffisamment longtemps pour qu'une contestation de la clôture ait amplement eu le temps de se manifester.
- La question ne me semble pas être améliorable pour pouvoir être rouverte, sauf à la changer tellement qu'il vaudrait mieux en poser une nouvelle.
- La question n'a pas de réponse qui apporte grand-chose par rapport à ce qu'on peut trouver ailleurs sur Internet ou dans un dictionnaire.

Dans ton profil, les liens « deleted recent questions » et « deleted recent answers » mènent à la liste des questions et réponses effacées respectivement, limitée aux [effacements récents](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185491/what-is-the-deleted-recent-questions-page-in-the-user-profile/185492#185492) (derniers 60 jours). Après cela, tu peux encore afficher les questions dont tu es l'auteur, mais il faut avoir gardé le lien quelque part.

---

Je pense que tu fais référence à la question [Ressources pour étudiants avancés](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8143/ressources-pour-%C3%A9tudiants-avanc%C3%A9s) — je ne trouve pas de question, effacée ou non, que tu aurais posée qui parle spécifiquement de livres de grammaire. Cette question n'est pas convenable pour Stack Exchange car la formule des questions-réponses se prêtre très mal aux listes de ressources, surtout avec des critères aussi généraux et vagues. D'ailleurs, cette question avait attiré très exactement zéro ressources en plus de celles que tu avais toi-même proposées.

Nous avons d'autres questions du même type, tout aussi inutiles mais non closes. J'invite la communauté de French Language Stack Exchange à participer au ménage !

[image: déchets dans un cadre doré]